# how to view newest replies from my followed users

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i am creating a following system in my website.

now when a user follows lets say three users and each user has lets say 3-4 messages.

when one of the users replies to a new message that has been sent to him i want this message to be the top message to be displayed.

what i am getting now is that the messages will go in stacks for each user even if it is a new message.

here is my php and queries:

```
$uid=$_SESSION['active_user_id'];

    $usersFollowingsQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT mr.*, f.* FROM messages_reply mr INNER JOIN follow f on mr.from_id = f.followed_id
WHERE follower_id = ? ORDER BY follow_id desc");
    $usersFollowingsQuery->bindValue(1,$uid);
    $usersFollowingsQuery->execute();
    if($usersFollowingsQuery->rowCount()==0){

        echo"<div class ='forgot'>Follow users to find their content here</div>";
    }
    else{
        echo"<div class ='forgot'>This is your feed</div>";
    while($row3 =$usersFollowingsQuery->fetch()){
    $followed_id = $row3['followed_id'];

    $usersPicQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $usersPicQuery->bindValue(1,$followed_id);
    $usersPicQuery->execute();
    $row2 = $usersPicQuery->fetch();


                    $d=$row['date'];

                ?>
                <div Class="inside-card" style="width:95%; margin-top:24px;"
                    <td>
                        <div class="msg-body">
            </a>
                </img>
                            <p style="font-size:16px; color:#696969"><?php echo $row3['question']; ?></p>



                    <div class="msg-action">
                    <div>
                <a href=<?php echo "'q=" . $row2['username'] . "'" ;?>> <img src=<?php echo "'" . $row2['picture'] . "'";?> width="32px" height="32px" > 
                    <p ><?php echo "" . $row2['username'] . "" ;?></p></a>
                    <span class="msg-icon" ><?php echo timeAgo($d); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <p  ><?php echo $row3['answer']; ?></p>


                    </div>
                    </td>                       
                </tr>
                </div>

            <?php   
                    } 

            }


    echo"</div>";
```

how can i modify my query such that whenever one of my followers replies to a new message it becomes the first message to be displayed regardless of who i followed first?

Comment: what the last message  of your follower, that is nit enough information to havre a guess

Comment: I don’t understand your comment

Comment: my comment tells you that you have to post more information about your tables. your tree select look like they could be done on one swoop. because all tables should be related.

Comment: okay let me modify my question @nbk

Comment: @nbk please check the edits, i created one query that does the exact same thing. but now how will i let my query bring the latest reply from any of my followers?

Comment: Add a "DateInserted" column to your MySQL table that will log when a message was created. Eg. `DateInserted TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Then you can order your query using that column.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs i already have a date column as you can see in my code, what can i modify in my query to request that?

Comment: From your code I can only see you are trying to access element `date` in the undefined `$row` variable. I can not see where `$row` is declared, or your database structure since you are using wildcards to select. Use ORDER BY date DESC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, only needed to add `order by date desc`

Comment: Disappointingly, this answer is unlikely to be of much help to others.

Comment: If they read the question and look at the query, and look at the comments and take the effort to understand it will help them. I am the one asking the question and found the answer with a little help from a user in the comments.